# Error RijndaelManaged, "Padding is invalid and cannot be removed"

Tags: c#, .net, encryption

I have error from `CryptoStream`:

> Padding is invalid and cannot be removed.

#### Code

```
public MemoryStream EncrypteBytes(Stream inputStream, string passPhrase, string saltValue)
{
    RijndaelManaged RijndaelCipher = new RijndaelManaged();
    RijndaelCipher.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
    RijndaelCipher.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
    byte[] salt = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(saltValue);
    PasswordDeriveBytes password = new PasswordDeriveBytes(passPhrase, salt, "SHA1", 2);

    ICryptoTransform Encryptor = RijndaelCipher.CreateEncryptor(password.GetBytes(32), password.GetBytes(16));
    MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
    CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, Encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write);
    var buffer = new byte[1024];
    var read = inputStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    while (read > 0)
    {
        cryptoStream.Write(buffer, 0, read);
        read = inputStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    }

    cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();
    memoryStream.Position = 0;
    return memoryStream;
}

// Example usage: DecryptBytes(encryptedBytes, "SensitivePhrase", "SodiumChloride");
public byte[] DecrypteBytes(MemoryStream memoryStream, string passPhrase, string saltValue)
{
    RijndaelManaged RijndaelCipher = new RijndaelManaged();
    RijndaelCipher.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;

    RijndaelCipher.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
    byte[] salt = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(saltValue);
    PasswordDeriveBytes password = new PasswordDeriveBytes(passPhrase, salt, "SHA1", 2);

    ICryptoTransform Decryptor = RijndaelCipher.CreateDecryptor(password.GetBytes(32), password.GetBytes(16));


    CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, Decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read);
    byte[] plainBytes = new byte[memoryStream.Length];

    int DecryptedCount = cryptoStream.Read(plainBytes, 0, plainBytes.Length);

    return plainBytes;
}
```

Comment: You're either using a different `passPhrase` or a different `saltValue` (or both) between encrypting and decrypting, as your code seems to work for me.

Comment: You might be interested in [`Stream.CopyTo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd782932.aspx) to simplify your code. If your messages are short (they seem to be since you're using `MemoryStream`) you can throw out all those streams entirely and just use `encryptor.TransformFinalBlock`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use `PaddingMode.Zeros` to fix problem , Following code:

```
   public byte[] EncryptFile(Stream input, string password, string salt)
            {

                // Essentially, if you want to use RijndaelManaged as AES you need to make sure that:
                // 1.The block size is set to 128 bits
                // 2.You are not using CFB mode, or if you are the feedback size is also 128 bits

                var algorithm = new RijndaelManaged { KeySize = 256, BlockSize = 128 };
                var key = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(salt));

                algorithm.Key = key.GetBytes(algorithm.KeySize / 8);
                algorithm.IV = key.GetBytes(algorithm.BlockSize / 8);
                algorithm.Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros;

                using (Stream cryptoStream = new MemoryStream())
                using (var encryptedStream = new CryptoStream(cryptoStream, algorithm.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    CopyStream(input, encryptedStream);

                    return ReadToEnd(cryptoStream);
                }
            }

            public byte[] DecryptFile(Stream input, Stream output, string password, string salt)
            {
                // Essentially, if you want to use RijndaelManaged as AES you need to make sure that:
                // 1.The block size is set to 128 bits
                // 2.You are not using CFB mode, or if you are the feedback size is also 128 bits
                var algorithm = new RijndaelManaged { KeySize = 256, BlockSize = 128 };
                var key = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(salt));

                algorithm.Key = key.GetBytes(algorithm.KeySize / 8);
                algorithm.IV = key.GetBytes(algorithm.BlockSize / 8);
                algorithm.Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros;

                try
                {
                    using (var decryptedStream = new CryptoStream(output, algorithm.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                    {
                        CopyStream(input, decryptedStream);
                        return ReadToEnd(output);
                    }
                }
                catch (CryptographicException ex)
                {
                    throw new InvalidDataException("Please supply a correct password");
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw new Exception(ex.Message);
                }
            }
```

I hop help you.

Comment: Hi @amir do you have the CopyStream and ReadToEnd function for this code , i tried some alternates for it and getting some bug while decryption.

Answer (score 11):

Please check your pass phrase - it should be same in both methods EncrypteBytes and DecrypteBytes. If both are not same, then it will generate the error.

Comment: see the error on mentioned link https://www.flickr.com/photos/97185741@N08/13893695390/

Comment: @HenkHolterman: if your not 101% sure then do not make down vote.

Comment: Seems you're right, had to test that first. Still think the length computations are fishy. You'll have to edit before I can cancel the vote.

Comment: It's not fair! Your answer should be marked correct! Thank you.

Comment: +1 Your answer is correct. I changed my key and recreated this. Writing a try catch to capture this error and return a more appropriate response. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

My problem was I was taking the encryped output in bytes and converting it to a string. The string back to byte array (for decrypting) was not the same. I was using UTF8Encoding, then I tried ASCIIEnconding. Neither worked.

Convert.FromBase64String/ToBase64String worked fine, got rid of the padding issues and actually decrypted the data.

Answer (score -1):

It's work

```
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream( absolute, FileMode.Open )) {
    // create a CryptoStream in read mode
    using (CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream( fs, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read )) {
        int readLength = ( int )fs.Length;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[readLength];
        cryptoStream.Read( buffer, 0, readLength );
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream( buffer )) {
            BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter( );
            settings = ( SettingsJson )bf.Deserialize( ms );// Deserialize SettingsJson array
        }
    }
    fs.Close( );
}
```