# Padding is invalid and cannot be removed with Rijndael

Tags: c#, encryption, rijndael

when i use this code to encrypt and decrypt i got an error said

Padding is invalid and cannot be removed.

any idea

```
public static class Crypto
{

    private static readonly byte[] initVectorBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("tu89geji340t89u2");

    // This constant is used to determine the keysize of the encryption algorithm.
    private const int keysize = 256;

    public static string Encrypt(string plainText, string passPhrase)
    {
        byte[] plainTextBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plainText);
        using (PasswordDeriveBytes password = new PasswordDeriveBytes(passPhrase, null))
        {
            byte[] keyBytes = password.GetBytes(keysize / 8);
            using (RijndaelManaged symmetricKey = new RijndaelManaged())
            {
                symmetricKey.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
                using (ICryptoTransform encryptor = symmetricKey.CreateEncryptor(keyBytes, initVectorBytes))
                {
                    using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        using (CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                        {
                            cryptoStream.Write(plainTextBytes, 0, plainTextBytes.Length);
                            cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();
                            byte[] cipherTextBytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
                            return Convert.ToBase64String(cipherTextBytes);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static string Decrypt(string cipherText, string passPhrase)
    {
        byte[] cipherTextBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(cipherText);
        using (PasswordDeriveBytes password = new PasswordDeriveBytes(passPhrase, null))
        {
            byte[] keyBytes = password.GetBytes(keysize / 8);
            using (RijndaelManaged symmetricKey = new RijndaelManaged())
            {
                symmetricKey.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
                using (ICryptoTransform decryptor = symmetricKey.CreateDecryptor(keyBytes, initVectorBytes))
                {
                    using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(cipherTextBytes))
                    {
                        using (CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                        {
                            byte[] plainTextBytes = new byte[cipherTextBytes.Length];
                            int decryptedByteCount = cryptoStream.Read(plainTextBytes, 0, plainTextBytes.Length);
                            return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(plainTextBytes, 0, decryptedByteCount);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23406135/error-rijndaelmanaged-padding-is-invalid-and-cannot-be-removed

Comment: yes and it did not work

Comment: How long is the data you are encrypting/decrypting?

Comment: Have you tried this _"The suggestions in other replys will sometimes work, by chance, but what you really need to do is set RijndaelAlg.Padding to PaddingMode.ISO10126, PaddingMode.PKCS7, or PaddingMode.ANSIX923. Any one of these 3 values should work, provided that you use the same value when encrypting and decrypting. Other values will work with some data, but not with all data. The above URL explains why."_ (from here https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d1788582-bf8c-43ec-a686-49647c359136/unexplained-cryptographicexception-padding-is-invalid?forum=netfxbcl)

Comment: @PaulF about 10 numbers like "1234567890"

Comment: _"The block of data to be encrypted must be as long as the key - in your case 16 bytes. Since you did not get an exception during encryption, the implementation you used "somehow" filled the remaining 12 bytes.
 I would suggest that you do that yourself - add some 12 bytes to your data (could be a random amount of bytes), encrypt it, and after decrypting just throw away those extra bytes."_ (from here : http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/350156/RijndaelManaged-Padding-is-invalid)

Answer (score 1):

I tried the following using your methods and it worked fine:

```
var passPhrase = "123456";
var e = Encrypt("testtesttesttest", passPhrase);
Console.WriteLine(e); // YEtSJshcn686ZO+JlEQ48ap/odhuvIGalbAT1XhinqQ=
var d = Decrypt(e, passPhrase);
Console.WriteLine(d); // testtesttesttest
```

This suggests that you're either passing a different `passPhrase` to `Decrypt()` to the one you passed to `Encrypt()`, or that you are somehow corrupting the ciphertext prior to decryption. (Are you perhaps calling `Decrypt` with the ciphertext and passphrase parameters reversed?)

It's also worth noting that essentially everything in the comments at the top of your code is wrong:

- You're *not* passing any salt to `PasswordDeriveBytes`.
- The size of the IV must be equal to the *block size* (16 bytes), it is unrelated to the key size used.
- Passing a 16 character string through `Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes()` results in a 16 byte output, *not* 32 bytes. (This rather coincidentally means that your `initVectorBytes` is in fact the correct length for the IV).

Furthermore, `PasswordDeriveBytes` is deprecated and should not be used. You should be using `Rfc2898DeriveBytes` instead, and you should be using a proper salt value. The IV should also not be a static value, and definitely not one derived from an ASCII string!

Comment: sorry i remove the old method without removing the comment

Comment: @tito11 Did you look at the rest of the answer? I couldn't reproduce the error you describe, suggesting the issue lies in the code you *haven't* shown. I suggest editing your question to show how you are using these methods, and that will actually exhibit the error if dropped into Visual Studio and run. (See: http://sscce.org/)